# K&R's C Program pg. 17 Line Counting Program results always 0

Tags: c

I have been reading K&R's The C Programming Language. When I typed in the example program on page 17 to count lines, the program always results are always 0. Here is my code:

```
/* Taken from The C Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan and 
 * Dennis M. Ritchie */

/* Include statement added for compatibility */
#include "stdio.h"

main()    /* count lines in input */
{
  int c, nl;

  nl = 0;
  /* EOF in Linux is ctrl-D and ctrl-Z on Windows */
  while ((getchar()) != EOF)
    if (c == '\n')
      ++nl;
  printf("%d\n", nl);
}
```

Comment: Is this code identical in every way to the K&R version?

Comment: No. I mistyped it as you can see from the answer below. I still can not believe it to be honest. I looked it over and over for what felt like a half of an hour and still missed my mistype. Thank you for all of your responses though. So sorry for doing that.

Answer (score 4):

```
while ((getchar()) != EOF)
```

should be

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Does your copy of the book really get that wrong?  I checked mine, which is the Second Edition, and it has the program on page 19 rather than your 17, and the code is correct.

Something that will pay huge dividends for you as you begin to program in C is to *always* enable all available compiler diagnostics.  In this case, `gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror` refuses to compile this program, saying:

```
error: ‘c’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=uninitialized]
```

Comment: Nice catch.  FWIW, I wouldn't write it this way; I would write two separate lines of code.  It's this kind of cuteness that gets people into trouble.

Comment: No. It does not! So sorry. I just read right over it like a dozen times! I can't believe it! So sorry! Thank you very much for answering!

Comment: OK, no problem, please please please enable your compiler warnings, extra warnings, and errors next time.  This will avoid lots of question-writing.  :)

Comment: I see. You already added the how to add warnings! Thank you very much! I will definitely use that from now on. My copy of the book is the first edition. It is very very old and beat up.